# Admin Audit API Quota Limit Issue

Tags: google-admin-audit-api

We have recently requested that the daily API access limit for our use of the Admin Audit API be increased, but that request has not yet been addressed.  We also enabled billing for our API Console project with the hope that we would not be limited to the courtesy limit.  But, we continue to hit our daily limit.

So my questions are:

- What is the expected turn-around time for acting on rate limit increases?
- For APIs that do not have pricing, does enabling billing allow us to exceed the courtesy limit?

Answer (score 0):

Q) What is the expected turn-around time for acting on rate limit increases?
A) The turn-around time is about a week depending on how much extra quota you are requesting.

Q) For APIs that do not have pricing, does enabling billing allow us to exceed the courtesy limit?
A) You will still have to fill out the request form. The billing part is just for purchasing additional quota for api that has pricing.